# Confused in Events & RelayCommand (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, events, mvvm

I am a beginner in Events, trying to built a MVVM......

**Question 1:

Referring to some online example of overriding a ArrayList class with events: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx

```
public delegate void ChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
public class ListWithChangedEvent: ArrayList 
{
    public event ChangedEventHandler Changed; 
    protected virtual void OnChanged(EventArgs e) {if (Changed != null) Changed(this, e);}
    ...
}
```

Am I correct to say that if I override any class by adding an event into it, whenever any member/method inside the overrided class was changed/called, the method OnChanged will be automatically run? (and I can see it when debugging?)

**Question 2:

Sorry quite confused with what is doing inside RelayCommand. Specifically why in the EventHandler CanExecuteChanged it Add and then Remove the method from the ConfigurationManager simultaneously?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As for your 1st question, I think you misunderstand something; just adding a method called OnChanged does not have the effect you describe. As with any other method, it must be called by some other code to be executed. As the base class and its methods do not know anything about the derived class, they do not invoke the method/event - and not even "by convention" because it is named OnChange. 
I'm not sure whether I understand your 2nd question correctly. The CanExecuteChanged event is used to notify the UI that something has changed that influences whether a command can or cannot be executed. I don't know your code or the sample you are referring to in regards to ConfigurationManager, but removing and adding an event handler is generally done in order to assert that an event handler is registered exactly once. If you register an event handler several times, it is called multiple times - a behavior one would rarely want. Therefore one removes the event handler before registering it anew.